# Why updated_at on mongodb not working? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My code to insert data is like this :

```
Message::create([
    'subject'       => $subject,
    'information'   => $information,
    'created_at'    => Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at'    => Carbon::now()
]);
```

When the code executed, the result is like this :

> subject:test
>
> information:test test test
>
> created_at:2017-03-13 20:32:29.000
>
> updated_at:1969-12-21 09:24:58.298

Should updated_at = created_at

Why the results are different?

Comment: That's funny. What is happening to that carbon instance after it is assigned. This stores a carbon instance, not the string date... try adding the
 ->toDateTimeString() to extract a string... Need to figure out what happens to that carbon instance between assignment and display...